# Is there a reset zoom option for VictoryZoomContainer? If not, how can I create an implementation of it?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, victory-charts

Need a victory inbuilt button or an API of Victory-Native to reset zoom of Victory Zoom Container.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same issue and ended up making a `componentDidUpdate` that checks if `prevprops.(state) !== this.props.(state)` and sets the `zoomDomain` to null.

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (prevProps.usState !== this.props.usState) {
    this.setState({
      zoomDomain: null
    })
  }
}
```